# Can I use trezor as a backend?

Tags: full-node, server, trezor

One of my clients (who has a Bitcoin Node deployed) is interested in being able to use Trezor to accept payments.

The most important thing is the creation of a new address, obtaining information about transactions.

If there is such a possibility, how is it synchronized remotely from the server?

Comment: Hi localhost01, can you clarify your question? What kind of business relationship do you have with your client, what is it they hope to achieve by using Trezor specifically, and why would this setup need a remote server?

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad They do not want to use Trezor, as well as Bitcoin Backend. This is funny, but it seems that the client himself is confused in what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

### Creating new addresses

Trezor and other hardware wallets generate addresses in a deterministic manner, and they allow exporting a master public key (also called "xpub") which can be used by other software to generate the same addresses. This is convenient because it allows receiving payments without direct access to the hardware wallet, you only need it for sending.

### Obtaining information from a server

Bitcoin is a peer-to-peer network with no servers. If you're running a node, you have information about every transaction that has ever happened. You can import the master public key into the node's wallet and scan the blockchain for transactions associated with it.